# How to extend selection backward in javascript?

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I am using working on a user-interface that provides buttons to select text instead of mouse click and drag. The user gets a textbox `selection`  to input the text to be selected, and a group of buttons:

1. for making selection
2. extending selection to the next word
3. extending selection to the previous word

The code works perfectly for the first two tasks above. Extending selection backward is working but not the way I want.

**Desired functionality:**
**Passage:** This is an example. Enter some text from this passage to the input box below and then press the select button to select it.
**Selection:** from this
**Extend Selection backwards:** (at the moment) from
**Extend Selection backwards:** (should select) text from this
i.e. I want to move the `anchor` one word backwards. How can I achieve it.

```js
getSelectionText = function() {
  sentence = document.getElementById("sentence");
  target = document.getElementById("target");
  selection = window.getSelection();
  range = document.createRange();
  index = sentence.innerHTML.indexOf(target.value);
  range.setStart(sentence.firstChild, index);
  range.setEnd(sentence.firstChild, (index + target.value.length));
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

removeSelection = function() {
  selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
}

extendSelection = function(buttonId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(buttonId);
  if (element.id == "Previous") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.modify("extend", "left", "word");
  } else if (element.id == "Next") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.modify("extend", "right", "word");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sentence">This is an example. Enter some text from this passage to the input box below and then press the select button to select it.
  </div>
  </br>
  <b> Selection: </b>
  <input type="text" id="target" value="an example" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="getSelectionText()">
  <button type="button" value="Remove Selection" onclick="removeSelection()"> Remove Selection</button>
  <button type="button" id="Previous" onclick="extendSelection('Previous')">Extend Selection
    < Previous</button>
  <button type="button" id="Next" onclick="extendSelection('Next')">Extend Selection > Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very pretty, but the following solution worked for me. The code snippet below contains an additional method `previousWord` which converts the `sentence` to array and returns the word immediately previous to the selection. Pressing `Move Selection` resets the start of `selection` to include the previous word, and pressing it repeatedly works fine as well.

```js
getSelectionText = function() {
  sentence = document.getElementById("sentence");
  target = document.getElementById("target");
  selection = window.getSelection();
  range = document.createRange();
  index = sentence.innerHTML.indexOf(target.value);
  range.setStart(sentence.firstChild, index);
  range.setEnd(sentence.firstChild, (index + target.value.length));
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

removeSelection = function() {
  selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
}

extendSelection = function(buttonId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(buttonId);
  if (element.id == "Previous") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.modify("extend", "left", "word");
  } else if (element.id == "Next") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.modify("extend", "right", "word");

  } else if (element.id == "Move") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    target = " " + previousWord() + " ";
    indexPW = sentence.innerHTML.indexOf(target);
    range.setStart(sentence.firstChild, indexPW + 1);
    range.setEnd(sentence.firstChild, (index + selection.toString().length));
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}


previousWord = function() {
  var pw = "";
  var sentence = document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML;
  var selection = window.getSelection();

  index = sentence.indexOf(selection);

  var sentArray = sentence.split(" ");

  var firstWord = selection.toString().split(" ")[0];

  var firstWordIndex = sentArray.indexOf(firstWord);
  if (firstWordIndex >= 1) {
    pw = sentArray[firstWordIndex - 1];
  } else {
    pw = sentArray[0];
  }
  return pw;
}
```

```html
<div id="sentence">This is an example. Select text chunk of any length and then press the button below.</div>
</br>
<b> Selection: </b> <input type="text" id="target" value="an example" />
<br> <br>
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="getSelectionText()">
<button type="button" value="Remove Selection" onclick="removeSelection()"> Remove Selection</button>
<button type="button" id="Previous" onclick="extendSelection('Previous')">Undo Extend</button>
<button type="button" id="Next" onclick="extendSelection('Next')">Extend Selection > Next</button>
<button type="button" id="Move" onclick="extendSelection('Move')">Move Selection</button>
```